# Function for Label in ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

Heyo! I'm working on a project with an API. The data for the API contains several dates. I wish to set up a function in the labels which has all the dates required for the API. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Could you explain a little better what you want? Can you give an example of the input and output?

Answer (score 0):

Call your API to get the dates for the labels. In the callback function of your API call, use the returned data to initialize the labels array and draw the chart.